# Java - Change border color JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Mi problema consiste en que yo tengo un `JPanel` al cual le he añadido un borde con `titledborder` de color verde, pero si me apretan un `JButton` quiero que ese borde se vuelva rojo. Lo único que me falta es saber como cambiar el color de ese borde una vez ya he hecho el `action listener` del botón.

Comment: Tendrás que poner los botones a la escucha `btn.addMouseListener(new Pulsado());` de eventos de ratón. interfaz `MouseListener` o en su defecto la clase adaptadora para no tener que implementar todos los métodos del ratón `MouseAdapter`

Comment: También deberías poner el código relevante para que podamos ayudarte en condiciones.

Answer (score 0):

En windows 10 podes hacerlo asi:

```
//en el main
UIDefaults uiDefaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
uiDefaults.put("activeCaption", new javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource(Color1));
uiDefaults.put("activeCaptionText", new javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource(Color2));
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

Cambiando color1 y color2 por los colores que quieras

Comment: no afecta si ya aplico un L&F antes? Esto debe ser antes o despues de el setVisible?